# Applying projection to vector

Tags: javascript, math, 3d, webgl

I'm building a simple 3d framework and have come across an issue when applying my projection matrix to a vector.

This is the code I am using the calculate my perspective project:

```
var t = near * Math.tan(fov * Math.PI / 180);
var n = far - near;

//  width   height      near                         far
this.setValues( near / (t * aspect),    0,             0,                  0,
                        0,           near / t,         0,                  0,
                        0,              0,      -(far + near) / n, -(2 * far * near) / n,
                        0,              0,            -1,                  1 );
```

And then applying my projection to my vector like so:

```
var w = 1 / ( x * e[3] ) + ( y * e[7] ) + ( z * e[11] ) + e[15];

this.x  = (x * e[0] + y * e[4] + z * e[8] + e[12]) * w;
this.y  = (x * e[1] + y * e[5] + z * e[9] + e[13]) * w;
this.z  = (x * e[2] + y * e[6] + z * e[10] + e[14]) * w;
```

The problem is the vector will always become [ X:  NaN  Y:  NaN  Z:  -Infinity  ].

I can't understand why its not returning a numerical value? This is what the calculated projection matrix looks like below.

```
 -----------------
 | 0.5570236439499305, 0, 0, 0 |  
 | 0, 1.0000000000000002, 0, 0 | 
 | 0, 0, -1.0618556701030928, -61.855670103092784 |
 | 0, 0, -1, 1 | 
 -----------------
```

Comment: What are the values you're inputing?  And your array should actually be a matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to fix this issue by changing the vector projection code to the following:

```
var w = ( x * e[3] ) + ( y * e[7] ) + ( z * e[11] ) + e[15];

this.x  = (x * e[0] + y * e[4] + z * e[8] + e[12]) / w;
this.y  = (x * e[1] + y * e[5] + z * e[9] + e[13]) / w;
this.z  = (x * e[2] + y * e[6] + z * e[10] + e[14]) / w;
```

It seems removing the / 1 from the w calculation fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting `NaN`s and `Infinity`s -- check all of your variables and make sure you're not getting any non numbers there. Dividing by 0 (with a negative number) will return `-Infinity`, so some of your values are resulting in that.